# Error when i click the button for move to the next page

Tags: java, android-studio, button, searchview

When i click on button, this is happening:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeAAG.png

The button is for getting the value from the searchView when the user fill it. And for open the next activity.
onclick:

```
 String state;
 SearchView searchView;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
searchView=(SearchView)findViewById(R.id.search_product);
        Button get_product=findViewById(R.id.get_product);
        get_product.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String product=searchView.toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, The_End.class);
                intent.putExtra("product", product);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),product,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });
        }
```

Here is my xml with button and searchView:

```
    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_product"
        android:layout_width="249dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:background="#CCCDFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.285" />
<Button
        android:id="@+id/get_product"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next "
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.839"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search_product"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.885" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String product = searchView.toString();`

that provides you viewId for SearchView used.Instead to get text from searchView you need to use

```
String product = searchView.getQuery().toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

In `String product=searchView.toString();` you are not fetching the value of searchview, you are fetching refrence of searchview and converting it to string using `toString()` which should not be done.

To get the contents of searchview you need to use `searchView.getQuery()` and then put the result in your  `intent.putExtra("product", searchView.getQuery());`